# How do we assign pre-fix characters in Switch and Format function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am wondering how to add characters to format function while keeping 2 decimals

It runs perfect when

```
Measure = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Country]),
          "EUR", FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "€0.00"),
          "US",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "$0.00"),
          "UK",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "£0.00"))
```

However, i want to add a character into it , it comes with  out of present range.

```
Measure = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Country]),
          "EUR", FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "EUR0.00"),
          "US",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "USD0.00"),
          "UK",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "UK0.00"))
```

Also , the DAX function only allows certain characters , for example

```
 Measure = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Country]),
          "EUR", FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "ppppp0.00"),    it works
          "US",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "h0.00"),      doesn't work
          "UK",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "l0.00"))         it works
```

Any idea how this happens guys ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Measure = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Country]),
      "EUR", FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "EUR" & "0.00"),
      "US",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), """USD""" & "0.00"),
      "UK",  FORMAT(SUM(Table[Sales]), "UK" & "0.00"))
```